# Flash movie randomly freezes the browser

Tags: windows, 64-bit, flash, freeze, flash-player

Just recently it seems that my flash player have had some troubles to display flash videos (youtube/dailymotions and others like this). This issue was supposed to be fixed with Flash Player 10 beta if I remember correctly.

My flash player is currently at the lastest version available (10.0.45.2) I'm currently on Windows 7 x64.

I tried to uninstall it and reboot and reinstall it, didn't work.

Sometimes when it freeze and I reboot it "fixes" temporary the problem. The freeze problem is each and every browser. If one fails and freeze, every browsers using the plugin or ActiveX (Opera 10.5/Chrome 5/Safari 4/IE 8/FF 3.7 all installed) will freeze upon playing.

I'm quite out of inspirations for fixing this up now I dare say.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flash switcher and try out several different versions of flash to see if that fixes the problem.  http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2006/10/flash_switcher_for_firefox.php

Answer (score 0):

Try Flash Player 10.1:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/

Or: Install Chrome-dev, and enable in-built flash player.
like this: --enable-internal-flash